# Kafka stream Consumed to CSV

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using Kafka in java, I'm consuming the JSON message as strings, the rate is 1 million messages per minute, I need to split the strings taking only some values and save it to CSV to load it into a database, how can I make something like that?

Comment: If you have data in Kafka, the best way to get it into a database is using the Kafka Connect JDBC sink connector. If that would be appropriate here then I can provide an answer.

Comment: i think it will , if you dont mind provide the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can stream data from a Kafka topic directly to a database using the [Kafka Connect JDBC sink](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-05-20&utm_term=rmoff-devx). To learn more about Kafka Connect see [the docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-05-20&utm_term=rmoff-devx) and [this talk](https://talks.rmoff.net/DQkDj3/from-zero-to-hero-with-kafka-connect).

Here's an example sink connector configuration:

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/demo",
    "topics": "test01",
    "connection.user": "connect_user",
    "connection.password": "asgard",
    "auto.create": true,
    "auto.evolve": true,
    "insert.mode": "insert",
    "pk.mode": "record_key",
    "pk.fields": "MESSAGE_KEY"
}
```

Learn more in this tutorial: https://rmoff.dev/kafka-jdbc-video

Learn about installing JDBC driver in Kafka Connect [here](https://rmoff.dev/fix-jdbc-driver-video)